# Microsoft Edge can't load pages but Chrome can

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge won't load any web pages get:

Hmmm...can't reach this page
(web address I am trying to reach)'s server IP address can't be found

Don't think it has anything to do with network settings since Chrome works fine.  But tried flushing cache, using google DNS server (8.8.8.8) instead of automatic settings, disabling IPv6, etc.  DNS service is running.  Checked for Malware.  Only security running is Windows defender.  Changed from Public to Private network.  Reset Edge settings.  No extensions installed.

Comment: Silly question. Have you tried to delete the entire Edge folder within the appropriate folder within %AppData%?

Answer (score 1):

You state: "Microsoft Edge won't load any web pages." What if you enter the IP address. For example, if you enter *142.251.40.110*, you should get a Google.com server.

If that works, then it's a DNS lookup issue, which you've tried fix; you might use another DNS server, such as Cloudflare 1.1.1.1, and use their separate IP addresses for *both* IPv4 and for IPv6.

If it does not, then the issue is in Edge, which can be repaired as follows:

- Press Windows, type `programs and fe`, and select *Programs and Features*.
- Right-click on *Microsoft Edge* and select *Change*.
- Click on the *Repair* button in the *Repair Microsoft Edge* dialog.

[image: Repair Edge]

If that does not help, you might need to reinstall Windows... or just use another browser, such as Google *Chrome* or Mozilla *Firefox*.

Comment: If I type in 142.251.40.110 then the address bar quickly changes to www.google.com and then won't load with same error (IP address can't be found).  I tried repairing Edge and it makes no difference.  Chrome continues to work just fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Repairing didn't help.  Don't want to reinstall Windows so we're giving up.  Thanks for suggestions, though.